# First steps with Craft Nitro: hostname not working after successful install

Tags: nitro

I installed Docker and Nitro and successfully used `nitro create <folder-name>`, and ended up with the 'Welcome to Craft CMS!' message.

I `cd`ed into the new folder and invoked `./craft setup`, which along the way has reported 'success!' at testing database credentials.

After saying yes to installing on the command line and creating an admin user account, I've received:

```
*** installed Craft successfully (time: 12.240s)

Generating project config files from the loaded project config ... done
```

I can see my new local dev instance running in Docker.app, but when I go to the site in a browser I get `503 – Service Unavailable`.

If I go to `{hostname}/admin` I get the browser prompt to Install Craft. If I try and fill that out I get `PDO exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

The potential ease of use of Nitro looks really promising so it's frustrating to be so close!

What could I be missing?

---

#### Update 1

I have the following in my `.env`:

```
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_SERVER=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=<dbname>
DB_USER=nitro
DB_PASSWORD=nitro
DB_SCHEMA=
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=
```

where `<dbname>` is the DB name I was asked to define (during `nitro create` I think) and which it said it could connect to.

Under 'Databases' `nitro context` reports:

```
Databases:
  engine:        mysql 5.6      hostname: mysql-5.6-3306.database.nitro
  username:      nitro  password: nitro
  port:  3306
```

---

#### Update 2

To start from scratch, I junked my nitro instance in Docker and uninstalled nitro, and then reinstalled it, and went through `nitro create` again, and…

ended up in basically the same place.

I've tried my custom database name as the value of `DB_DATABASE` and the default `nitro` database name, and it makes no difference.

Comment: Did you edit your `.env` file or have Nitro do it for you? Your `DB_*` values need to reference the details you get for the relevant database engine running `nitro context`.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Re the `.env` I did a combination of both I think. I have updated my question above with the current state.

Comment: Nitro should have updated `.env` so that `DB_SERVER=mysql-5.6-3306.database.nitro` in this case, not `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Ah, of course! So obvious now you point it out. That has worked thanks. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can vote for it?

Comment: Answered—thank you! :)

Comment: Heyy! I have the same Problem but i do have the right Database in the .env file. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Nitro?

Answer (score 3):

After cheating via discussion in the comments, I’m certain that your `DB_SERVER` is incorrectly set to `127.0.0.1` when it should in fact be `mysql-5.6-3306.database.nitro`.

In a perfect world this would have been set for you when Nitro edited `.env`, but in a pandemic-ravaged dystopia your next best option is to use whatever `nitro context` indicates.

Comment: FWIW the Craft starter project was tragically overwriting the `.env` Nitro likely set up for you with `nitro create`, [which we’ve fixed](https://github.com/craftcms/craft/releases/tag/1.1.3). Should be smoother sailing going forward!

Comment: Thanks for your help Matt :)